# Need help in a reverse pivot - Column names become data and then the values in that column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am looking to pull data from a table and insert the results into a #temp table where the column name is part of the result set.  I know I can get the column names from the schema information table but I need the data in one of the columns. There will be only 1 row from the original table, so I am basically doing a reverse STUFF command or reverse Pivot.  The result set would be columnName and Value but multiple rows- as many rows as columns

So basically the result set or table with have just 2 columns, one for the column name and one for the value in that column.  That is my goal. I know a pivot does this in reverse but can't seem to find a "Reverse pivot". I am using SQL Server 2008.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We on StackOverflow cannot help you without more information. Try adding some sample data and desired results from that sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to give a better description of what you're after? For example, more information on the table structures, etc.

Regardless. Please see below an example of using a `CROSS APPLY` statement to transform a 'Pivot Table' into a flat table.

**Data within the pivot table**

```
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName |    Company     |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | Joe       | Bloggs   | A Company      |
|  2 | Jane      | Doe      | Lost and Found |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

**SQL statement to turn pivot table to flat table**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('PivotedTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE PivotedTable

GO

CREATE TABLE PivotedTable (
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255),
    LastName VARCHAR(255),
    Company VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT PivotedTable (FirstName, LastName, Company)
    VALUES ('Joe', 'Bloggs', 'A Company'), ('Jane', 'Doe', 'Lost and Found')


SELECT
    FlatTable.ColumnName,
    FlatTable.Value
FROM PivotedTable t
CROSS APPLY (
VALUES
('FirstName', FirstName),
('LastName', LastName),
('Company', Company)
) FlatTable (ColumnName, Value)
```

**Output of the query after turning into a flat table**

```
+------------+----------------+
| ColumnName |     Value      |
+------------+----------------+
| FirstName  | Joe            |
| LastName   | Bloggs         |
| Company    | A Company      |
| FirstName  | Jane           |
| LastName   | Doe            |
| Company    | Lost and Found |
+------------+----------------+
```